# Openstack swift with ceph backend (radosgw)

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, ceph, radosgw

I am trying to use Openstack (liberty) swift with Ceph (Jewel) using radosgw. The aim is that the objects should be stored under ceph osds. I have a working Openstack and Ceph cluster.

To use Ceph as object storage backend I installed and configured radosgw in ceph cluster .  In openstack node I installed "python-swiftclient", created an object-store service and added an endpoint for that service with the URL of radosgw.

I followed the instructions given in the link below. 
http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/radosgw/keystone/

ceph.conf

```
[client.rgw.rgw]
rgw_frontends = "civetweb port=7480"
rgw enable ops log = true
rgw ops log rados = true
rgw thread pool size = 2000
rgw override bucket index max shards = 23
ms dispatch throttle bytes = 209715200

[client.radosgw.gateway]
rgw keystone url =  http://controller:35357
rgw keystone admin token = ADMIN
rgw keystone accepted roles =  _member_,admin
rgw keystone token cache size = 200
rgw keystone revocation interval = 60
rgw s3 auth use keystone = true
nss db path = /var/ceph/nss
```

Openstack endpoints

```
# openstack endpoint list |grep -i object
 | 8efd00b48db249e69244a5f3e35356b1 | RegionOne | swift | object-store | True | internal | http://rgw:7480/swift/v1 |
 | b7d1c7ccc84640138116d8e6676b28a3 | RegionOne | swift | object-store | True | admin | http://rgw:7480/swift/v1 |
 | c7844842b53647a4b623905c54cc6c75 | RegionOne | swift | object-store | True | public | http://rgw:7480/swift/v1 |
```

Output of swift list from command line

```
# swift list -v
test_CONTAINER
```

Output of swift stat from command line

```
# swift stat -v
          StorageURL: http://rgw:7480/swift/v1
          Auth Token: AUTH_rgwtk0e00000074657374757365723a737769667431dd200c6d2136112ee6d657300feb16d05ffa8f80a2e53ce6c257b32ec5505ff396e5e8
          Account: v1
          Containers: 7
          Objects: 12
          Bytes: 168
          Meta Temp-Url-Key: healthseq
          X-Account-Bytes-Used-Actual: 40960
          X-Timestamp: 1473615022.41820
          X-Trans-Id: tx0000000000000000006b3-0057d594ae-1f5cb-default
          Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
          Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

When I try to access the object store - container in openstack dashboard, I get the following error.
http://pastebin.com/ALEvYCX8

Please see the image below for the error that I get while trying to access the object store from dashboard.
[image: Error in the openstack dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

just remove this line in your code
[client.radosgw.gateway] and merge the setting